# I wrote code to replace chars in the string on javascript but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```js
function kebabToSnake(string){
  var replacedString = string;
  for(i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(string[i] === "-"){
       replacedString[i] = "_";
    }
  }
  return replacedString;
}
```

I am new in js, can someone explain why this code doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

String are immutable, that means, you can not assign a character to a position of the string.

You could use an array instead and relace only the wanted character. Later you need to join the array to a string.

```js
function kebabToSnake(string) {
    var replacedString = Array.from(string);
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        if (string[i] === "-"){
            replacedString[i] = "_";
        }
    }
    return replacedString.join('');
}

console.log(kebabToSnake('abc-def-ghi'));
```

A bit shorter approach by using the mapping parameter of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
function kebabToSnake(string) {
    return replacedString = Array
        .from(string, c => c === '-' ? '_' : c)
        .join('');
}

console.log(kebabToSnake('abc-def-ghi'));
```

Finally a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), which looks for a single minus sign `/-/` and replaces all (`g` - for global - flag) with an underscore `'_'`.

```js
function kebabToSnake(string) {
    return string.replace(/-/g, '_');
}

console.log(kebabToSnake('abc-def-ghi'));
```

Comment: or even shorter approach with regex :P

Comment: @NickParsons, of course, but i think, op would like to learn without.